# How do I run two AppleScripts simultantiously

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to figure out how to have two AppleScripts run simultaneously by clicking on the one icon. Currently I'm trying to use

```
set contentFile to myFolder & "Contents/Resources/Secondary.scpt"
do shell script "afplay " & quoted form of contentFile"
```

But I know the "afplay" is for audio not scripts. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [path to resource](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW20) to get the *pathname* of the `.scpt` file that's in an App's `Resource` folder, and then run the `.scpt` file using `osascript` e.g.:

```
set scptPath to POSIX path of (path to resource "Secondary.scpt")

do shell script "osascript" & space & scptPath
```